# simplexml_load_string function not loading XML file in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am busy with an EPP registration module which returns XML via a stream service.

The XML returns fine but I am unable to get  load using PHP's `simple_xml_load_string` or `new SimpleXMLElement` to correctly load the XML so that I can use the data as an object.

I am however able to return the XML back using `asXML()` so it would appear that the XML is loaded, I am just not able to get access to any of the values within the object. A `print_r()` of the object also returns an empty object (from what I understand this is correct).

Here is a sample of a login result:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <epp:epp xmlns:epp="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0">
   <epp:response>
     <epp:result code="1000">
       <epp:msg>Access granted</epp:msg>
     </epp:result>
     <epp:trID>
       <epp:clTRID>ABC-123456</epp:clTRID>
       <epp:svTRID>OTE-EPP-155A695A3C9-717E</epp:svTRID>
     </epp:trID>
   </epp:response>
 </epp:epp>
```

What I need to get access to is the result code above.

Here is sample PHP I have tried:

```
 // Note that the $var property contains the XML exactly as it is above.
 $result = simplexml_load_string($var); 
 echo $result->response->msg; // Nothing
 echo $result->asXML(); // Returns the XML correctly.
 $result = new SimpleXMLElement($var);
 print_r($result); // Returns an empty object.
 echo $result->response->msg; // Nothing
 echo $result->toXML(); // Returns the XML correctly.
```

Any ideas would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the manual [`simplexml_load_string`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) has the following parameters:

```
SimpleXMLElement simplexml_load_string ( string $data [, string $class_name = "SimpleXMLElement" [, int $options = 0 [, string $ns = "" [, bool $is_prefix = false ]]]] )
```

Therefore, I believe that you can load your XML this way :

```
simplexml_load_string($var, "SimpleXMLElement", 0, "epp", true);
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you, works like a charm :) Am I then right that the namespace was missing?

Comment: Exactly, you must tell the class that tags are prefixed with a namespace ;)